# Embed multiple tweets on one page via individual ids

Tags: jquery, twitter, oembed

I am trying to figure out a way with twitter's new guidelines that will allow me to embed specific tweets from different users dynamically into a webpage.
I have looked at [Twitter's oEmbed endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) and it seems like what I need, however I am not sure how to accomplish this via one ajax call.

I obviously do not want to make tons of calls to the Twitter server and max out, so is there a way to run a loop inside a ajax call to try different tweet ids without hitting the server multiple times?

Or is there another method I am not familiar with that someone could suggest?

I hope this is clear enough of a question, thanks for taking the time to read.

cheers

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var output = $("#output");
var ids = [ php code to build an array of IDs];

for(i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
   $.ajax({
 url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=' + ids[i] + '&align=center&callback=?',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $(data.html).appendTo(output);
    }
      });
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that is interested, the way i've accomplished this is to seek out and store the embedded tweet html blockquote into a database and just pump them out one by one...

for instance..

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>RT @<a href="https://twitter.com/nosherwan">nosherwan</a>: Enyojs of webOS fame is now open source and looks like a serious contender for multi platform application development</p>&mdash; Enyo (@EnyoJS) <a href="https://twitter.com/EnyoJS/status/263664668839645184" data-datetime="2012-10-31T15:32:10+00:00">October 31, 2012</a></blockquote>
```

Adding in the script tag once.

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This method fails incase you want to embed multiple tweets by getting their blockquote html from your database and insert it to your web page and render it, so even if one of the tweet is deleted by the user, the whole rendering fails and all you see is tweet text without css.